# Browser web page gets sync'd across different macBooks

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, google-chrome, big-sur

I have 2 macBook Pro's (Catalina and Big Sur) and somehow when I open any web page in Chrome/Brave browser on 1 macBook, it gets synced to the other macBook and a new Chrome icon opens up on the dock. And when I click that, the exact same page what I have opened up in my macBook gets opened on the other macBook.

I checked if the browser has sync enabled but it is not.

Can anyone suggest something I can do to stop the browsers from syncing across the macBooks ?

Comment: Are you logged into the same AppleID on both devices? And is Continuity/Handoff enabled?

Comment: @nohillside   Yes. And I just logged out of my apple id on 1 macbook. Let's say macBook A and B. I logged out of my apple id on macBook A. Now, whatever I browse on macBook A does not get synced with macBook B. But macBook B still keeps getting synced with macBook A.

Any idea how I can turn the continuity off? And is this something to be disabled on both laptops?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS uses [Continuity](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681) to sync application state between devices logged into the same AppleID. See the linked support page for ways to configure this in detail.

Comment: Yep. the HandOff setting was enabled on our laptops. I think that is the default when you login with your apple id. 

Thanks for helping out @nohillside